# How can i integrate device date and time picker in phonegap page?

Tags: cordova, datepicker, device, timepicker

In my phonegap app there is an appointment form with date and time fields. I need to integrate device date and time pickers in this page and also need to 
remove/disable past dates & already  booked time slots. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What platform does this relate to? Most platforms (iOS and later Android) have native support for the HTML5 input types "date", "time" and "datetime".

e.g. `<input type="date">`

If you're targeting a platform that does not have native support, there are Cordova/PhoneGap plugins available to achieve this: http://plugreg.com/search?q=date+time

Comment: I need this for all platforms.I tried with <input type="date"> but it just acts as normal text field.

Comment: Then you will need to use a plugin to achieve the functionality on the platforms you are developing for that do not support these input types. I wrote one for Windows Phone 8 (http://plugreg.com/plugin/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-datetime-picker) and there are others for iOS and Android (e.g. http://plugreg.com/plugin/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker)

Comment: Hi Lee Crossley i am using your plugin http://plugreg.com/plugin/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-datetime-picker for wp8. it runs good locally but when i build XAP not working,please give the plugin name <gap:plugin name="uk.co.ilee.datetimepicker> but not working

Comment: Note: the plugin is not supported by the PhoneGap build service - you must build locally

Comment: @LeeCrossley is the plugin supported now by phonegap? and from this website http://www.plugreg.com/plugin/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-datetime-picker it says that it supports win7 is that true because on github you didn't specify that and does it support i18n?